Eraser completely makes the Canvas white
main.js:
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
const AXIS_LENGTH = 50; // Length of the axis lines
let mouseX;
let mouseY;

// history so we can always redraw
var points = []
var allPoints = []
var invertedX, invertedY

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function startDrawing(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [canvas.width - (e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft), canvas.height - (e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop)];
  points = []
  allPoints.push(points)
  points.push([lastX, lastY])


}

function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  const x = canvas.width - (e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
  const y = canvas.height - (e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);

  [lastX, lastY] = [x, y];
  points.push([lastX, lastY])

}

function stopDrawing() {
  isDrawing = false;
}


function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function drawAllPoints() {
  allPoints.forEach(drawPoints)

}

function drawPoints(points) {

  if (points.length) {
    ctx.save()
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(points[i][0], points[i][1]);
      ctx.stroke();

    }
    ctx.restore()
  }
}

function drawEverything() {
  clearCanvas()
  drawAxis();
  drawAllPoints()

}

function drawAxis() {

  mouseX = invertedX
  mouseY = invertedY
  // Draw vertical axis line
  ctx.save()
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY - AXIS_LENGTH / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY + AXIS_LENGTH / 2);
  ctx.stroke();

  // Draw horizontal axis line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(mouseX - AXIS_LENGTH / 2, mouseY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX + AXIS_LENGTH / 2, mouseY);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore()
}


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', stopDrawing);
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  startDrawing(e.touches[0]);
});
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  draw(e.touches[0]);
});
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', stopDrawing);
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  const mouseX = event.clientX;
  const mouseY = event.clientY;

  invertedX = window.innerWidth - mouseX;
  invertedY = window.innerHeight - mouseY;

  drawEverything()
});

When I tried to erase the canvas by clicking the erase button, the every stroke in the canvas becomes white. I also have a cross hair thing that shows where the stroke is to be drawn. The controls are inverted. I used if else for the draw and erase. I used white color for the stroke which makes as the eraser tool. But when I click the btn and tried to drag, everything turns white but again clicking the btn makes evrything turns black.

Hey it's me again from Merging two canvas file
Remember that canvas is being redrawn from the memory variable allPoints. So we will add colors to that variable. BTW, this will make it easier to save and restore the drawing since it is already represented as variable.
Also, we were redrawing the canvas on mousemove. Lets make it right and use requestAnimationFrame


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;
const AXIS_LENGTH = 50; // Length of the axis lines
let mouseX;
let mouseY;


// history so we can always redraw
var points = []
var stroke = {}
var allPoints = []
var invertedX, invertedY
var chosenColor = "black"

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function startDrawing(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [canvas.width - (e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft), canvas.height - (e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop)];
  points = []
  stroke = {
    points: points,
    color: chosenColor
  }
  allPoints.push(stroke)
  points.push([lastX, lastY])
}


function drawColorButtons() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".toolbar .btn").forEach(function(btn) {
    var color = btn.getAttribute("data-color")
    btn.style.backgroundColor = color
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      chosenColor = color
    })
  })
}
drawColorButtons()

function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;

  const x = canvas.width - (e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
  const y = canvas.height - (e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);

  [lastX, lastY] = [x, y];
  points.push([lastX, lastY])

}

function stopDrawing() {
  isDrawing = false;
}


function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function drawAllPoints() {
  allPoints.forEach(drawStroke)

}

function drawStroke(stroke) {
  drawPoints(stroke.points, stroke.color)
}

function drawPoints(points, color) {
  if (points.length) {
    ctx.save()
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(points[i][0], points[i][1]);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.restore()
  }
}

function drawEverything() {
  clearCanvas()
  drawAllPoints()
  drawAxis();
  requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything)
}
drawEverything()


function drawAxis() {

  mouseX = invertedX
  mouseY = invertedY
  // Draw vertical axis line
  ctx.save()
  ctx.strokeStyle = chosenColor;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY - AXIS_LENGTH / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY + AXIS_LENGTH / 2);
  ctx.stroke();

  // Draw horizontal axis line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(mouseX - AXIS_LENGTH / 2, mouseY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX + AXIS_LENGTH / 2, mouseY);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore()
}


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', stopDrawing);
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  startDrawing(e.touches[0]);
});
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  draw(e.touches[0]);
});
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', stopDrawing);
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  const mouseX = event.clientX;
  const mouseY = event.clientY;

  invertedX = window.innerWidth - mouseX;
  invertedY = window.innerHeight - mouseY;

});
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  background: gray;
  display: block;
}

.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="btn" data-color="black"></div>
  <div class="btn" data-color="white"></div>
  <div class="btn" data-color="gray"></div>
  <div class="btn" data-color="red"></div>
  <div class="btn" data-color="green"></div>
  <div class="btn" data-color="yellow"></div>
  <div class="btn" data-color="blue"></div>
</div>




Hey! Thanks Man. I did not try this yet. But it is too laggy when there is a lot of strokes.

that makes sense. maybe you can use ctx.getImageData and ctx.putImageData to make the axis appear over the background. need some research.

for drawing in black you should ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'

See the cross hair is below the stroke like its z index is low. how can i bring it up? I am basic at canvas. Also ways to reduce lag

i replaced the order of drawing: first points, axis later.
